# Garmin Gps Battery Modification

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, gps

I recently bought a [GTU 10 from Garmin](http://www8.garmin.com/ces/gtu10.html).

I want to extend it's battery life by replacing and soldering on a new battery and enclosing the battery and the GTU 10 in a [1601 Otterbox.](http://www.otterbox.com/OtterBox-1601-GPS-Case-with-Magnet-Base/OTR3-1601S,default,pd.html)

I would like to be able to charge the new battery through the USB connector on the circuit board, so is it possible to do? What should be the specs on the new battery?

After removing the shell, you are left with a 3.7v, 740 mAh, 2.7Wh
battery and the circuit board.

Battery.

[image]

GPS Side

[image]

Answer (score 4):

What you are suggesting is fraught with difficulty and danger.  There will be an intelligent battery charger/monitor either built into the battery pack or on the Garmin baseboard.  This will have the characteristics of the supplied battery built into it, so replacing the battery with a larger capacity one will make the charger/monitor operate incorrectly or give an incorrect battery status.  Without knowing exactly how the battery pack information is used by the Garmin I cannot tell what the effects will be.

Many equipment manufacturers have taken to adding an [encrypted battery ID](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq26150.pdf) into the pack to prevent the use of cheap, poor quality replacement battery packs.  If this has been done then your Garmin will reject the replacement battery.

A solution to your problem could be to use a battery pack like [this one from Duracell](http://www.duracell.com/en-US/product/instant-usb-charger.jspx), or for you to design your own solution to feed 5V in through the USB connector.

Answer (score 1):

I would confirm with Garmin if the car power port will work ~11.1V and use the laptop size power packs These come on 3 series cells with 2 in parallel up to 4 in parallel. so look at 6, 9 and 12 cell packs.